# Flexsilder issue - playing in the descending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm not sure whether this is a css or JS issue. I have installed the flexslider plugin' which seems to have been installed correctly however I have a problems with the flexslider carousel, [code posted at github](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider). My sliders are playing in descending order, i'm not quite sure why or how it's doing this... below is the Jquery in corresponding JS

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshow:true,
    directionNav: true,
    minItems: 1,
    maxItems: 1,
    controlsContainer: false,
    manualControls: '.custom-controls li',
      start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```

[My Example Site](http://bodyworksforme.com/testing/ExpressionEngine/index.php?/home/index-copy)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are overriding flex-slider CSS from your own CSS? Maybe you have floated flex-slider's contents (image, div or what ever) to right or reverse direction? If so try to fix that :)

I have tested this after seeing your post. So I changed flex-slider inline float:left to float: right and now I get last slide as first slide and all slides are reversed.

Comment: are we talking the css property slides li ??

Comment: @NewBoy Ya I was talking about that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Flexslider  2.2.2. 
Downli
https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider